# How do I use a relative URL as a data source for a Timeline web part?

Tags: web-part, site-template, url

I am trying to create a site template for a project site.  On the home page of the site, I have a Timeline web part (new for SP 2013).  When the web part is created, the data source defaults to the site in which it was created.

[image: Fully-qualified URL]

However, when I create a site template based off of this site, it keeps the absolute URL as the data source.  This makes it so every time I create a site based off of that template, I have to go in and change that URL to the new site's URL.

Is there a way to have the data source be a relative URL so I don't have to change it whenever I create a new site?

#### Troubleshooting Steps Taken

I have already tried using an App Part for the task list, but the view includes not only the timeline but also the full list.  I just want the timeline.

Also, I have tried using just "/template", "/", and even "./" (I was desperate) as the URL, but I get the following error:  "The URL provided is invalid or does not have a valid timeline source. Check the provided URL and validate again."

[image]

#### Code

```
<WebPartPages:SPTimelineWebPart runat="server" TimelineType="TaskListTimeline" PageAddress="/sites/CEOsearch/template" TypeSelection="TaskListTimeline" SourceSelection="326925ea-a1c8-460c-a04c-23c3527e9aac" ListId="326925ea-a1c8-460c-a04c-23c3527e9aac" CurrentTaskListWebAddress="https://connect.contoso.org/sites/CEOsearch/template" ViewName="Timeline" Title="Timeline" FrameType="Default" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="Right" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_104ab0ec_0427_46ed_a9fc_7c1a412afeae" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{104AB0EC-0427-46ED-A9FC-7C1A412AFEAE}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></WebPartPages:SPTimelineWebPart>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a script at the end of the page and play with timeline datasource , if you look at the page source you will find some codes like this :

var tldsctl00_ctl33_g_7b5ad475_fefc_4682_ab26_d06bc119acf8 = new SP.UI.Timeline.ListTimelineDatasource(); tldsctl00_ctl33_g_7b5ad475_fefc_4682_ab26_d06bc119acf8.Init("5fb4b4b1-1da4-4eaf-a20d-a1c4952020d4", [{"ListRO":"0","ItemsRO":"0"}], "http://sharepoint/sites/en", "Timeline");

if you can change the url on init the datasource it would solve your problem .

Comment: Added code sample.  What should I change the URL to to get it to stay consistent when creating a template?